# 500 Internal Server Error Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel, frameworks

Sometimes i got this error: 500 Internal Server Error

My PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

My Laravel Version "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"

Apache Server

My DocumentRoot & Directory in httpd.conf is set to: /usr/local/sites/mysite-laravel/public

My server logs:

(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Mon Sep 01 14:52:33 2014] [error] mod_fcgid: process /var/www-data/fcgi-bin/php5-fcgi(25404) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11

Does anyone know about this? or is this is what happens in Laravel 4?

Comment: I have the same issue with the latest Laravel with fcgi on Apache2 on Ubuntu, all the latest upgrade.  The issue is not an error in the .htaccess file or the fcgi configuration, because if I add a simple test.php file with content `echo "Hello Word";` in the Laravel public folder, I can read it fine.  Permissions are the default permission with composer installation (755 for index.php) - this is not the issue either.

Comment: Here is a link to my similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292650/anyone-succeeded-to-install-laravel-on-apache2-with-fcgi

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your folders have `755` permission. I cleared this issue with permission. This is first thing do any others. You can get successful output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .htaccess on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the .htaccess configuration. Any syntax errors will cause a 500 Internal Server Error message to be displayed instead of your website.

To confirm whether a misconfiguration .htaccess is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the .htaccess file temporarily and then try to reload the page

PHP Coding Timing Out

if your PHP script makes external network connections, the connections may time out. If too many connections are attempted and time out, this will cause a "500 Internal Server Error." To prevent these time outs and errors, you'll want to make sure that PHP scripts be coded with some timeout rules. Typically, however, catching a timeout error when connecting to a database or externally to remote resources (example: RSS feeds) are difficult. They, in effect, freeze the script from continuing to run.

Removing any external connections can increase both the performance of your website and decrease the chances of you receiving a "500 Internal Server Error."

Comment: Hi, thank you for a quick reaction!

I don't think my ".htaccess" is causing the problem:           <code><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule></code>

Comment: Comment out RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] line and retest @WillfransVarónSáenz

Comment: Hi Josh Parker, fixed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great news can you give the answer a tick and a + 1 as i helped you out and i am wanting my rating to go up so i can use more features.. all i ask :) @WillfransVarónSáenz Thanks

Comment: Hi there, I got this 500 error again, i don't understand... I begin to wonder the use of something that is so hard to install...

Comment: I have a very similar issue. [Thu Mar 26 22:52:34.012794 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 30834] (104)Connection   reset by peer: [client 65.92.253.153:7785] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
    [Thu Mar 26 22:52:34.012862 2015] [core:error] [pid 30834] [client 65.92.253.153:7785] End of script output before headers: php-fcgi-wrapper
    [Thu Mar 26 22:52:39.826939 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 30830] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/default/cgi-bin/php5-default/php-fcgi-wrapper(31115) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11 Changing timeout configuration seems promising, but where?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen when the connection between client and server disconnected before complete the request.

I Solved this problem by increase the values of FastCGI configurations which located in file "/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf" (In Apache 2.4, CentOS 7) to this values:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestLen 10737418240
FcgidIOTimeout 36000
FcgidConnectTimeout 36000
FcgidBusyTimeout 36000
FcgidIdleTimeout 96000
FcgidProcessLifeTime 96000
</IfModule>
```