# Anyone succeeded to Install Laravel on Apache2 with fcgi?

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu-14.04, mod-fcgid

I have successfully installed Laravel on Apache2 with php as a module. The instructions are simple. However, when I try with fcgi it does not work. So it has to do with the server configuration.  After I visited `http://<mylaraveldomain>` (domain not public), I looked at /var/log/apache2/error.log and got this error message

```
[Thu Mar 26 22:52:34.012794 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 30834] (104)Connection   reset by peer: [client 65.92.253.153:7785] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Thu Mar 26 22:52:34.012862 2015] [core:error] [pid 30834] [client 65.92.253.153:7785] End of script output before headers: php-fcgi-wrapper
[Thu Mar 26 22:52:39.826939 2015] [fcgid:error] [pid 30830] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/default/cgi-bin/php5-default/php-fcgi-wrapper(31115) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

I also looked at all other log files in /var/log recently modified after visiting the URL, but no additional useful info was found.  Should I look elsewhere?   It is not that fcgi is not working, because if I put a file test.php in laravel public folder I can read it fine at the URL `http://<mylaraveldomain>/test.php`.  Is there some special configuration settings to make laravel works with fcgi ? It is possible that it is specific to my installation of fcgi.  So, I would like to know if others have succeeded to install laravel with fcgi on apache2. I am on Ubuntu and I made a recent apt-get upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I checked syslog and there was additional info. I could see a segment fault. I guessed it could be cache management issue. I commented out the line `zend_extension=opcache.so` in the file `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini` and it worked. Of course, this is only a work around.